# Which MP3 replay gain package?

Tags: music, mp3, replaygain

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and I want to normalise a lot of MP3 files recursively (i.e. including all subfolders from a main folder); the new replay level should be applicable across the entire collection, if possible; NOT album by album or folder by folder.

And I want the actual files to be updated, so I can play them on a primitive hardware MP3 player in a car, which probably won't be able to recognise replaygain tags.

The only information I've found so far is pretty old; I understand that MP3gain forked to rgain, and there are recommendations to use python replaygain, which may use the same technology. I know MP3gain normalised on the basis of perceived volume, rather than peak volume, and this is exactly what I still want.

It would be great if whatever I use has a GUI; not a deal breaker though.  Failing a GUI, some sort of manual, or at least a decent README would be helpful.

So which is the most recent/best package that matches the above requirements?

Cheers

John M.

Comment: I wonder if ffmpeg-normalize might interest you? https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize

Comment: Hi Andrew; thank you for your suggestion,  but I'm currently getting to grips with QMP3gain,  which offers a GUI for running MP3gain.  I know it's less efficient,  but I do like a GUI...   Cheers,  John